# BibTeX error when trying to compile an entry

Tags: bibtex

```
@ELECTRONIC{ios9,   
author = {{Apple Inc.},   
month = {September},  
year = {2015},   
title = {iOS Security},   
url = {https://ssl.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf/},  
timestamp = {2015.11.24}
```

I am unable to use this citation because of this error:

[image]

edit:

preface of document:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%\hyphenation{} %

\begin{document} \title{.....}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{......} \IEEEauthorblockA{.....,
HiG\\ Email: \texttt{.......}} }
```

EDIT 2: [overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrBUD.jpg) of situation

Alternative image source: [this](http://pasteboard.co/2pqxRZzj.png) and [this](http://pasteboard.co/2pqyOzgb.png) picture

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: IEEE bibliography

Comment: What's the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction?

Comment: I have no such instruction. I've written 3 articles with tons of citations without it, is it essential?

Comment: I still get "citation undefined" error in TeXstudio, but the error in bibtex changes to Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>  $ <to be read again> _ l.15 @comment{jabref-meta: selector_publisher:}. If I delete that comment, it says the error is in another similar comment about selector_author

Comment: Unrelated, but important: the option `cmex10` to `amsmath` is for compatibility with 20 year old TeX distribution and I bet you have a more recent one. The `pdftex` option should not be used with `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fatal errors in the bib entry you've posted: (i) A closing curly brace is missing at the end of the `author` field, and (ii) the entry itself also needs a terminating closing curly brace. Separately, you should also encase the `title` field in curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing the word "iOS".

After fixing things up, the entry should look like this:

```
@electronic{ios9,
  author = {{Apple Inc.}},
  month = {September},
  year = {2015},
  title = {{iOS Security}},
  url = {https://ssl.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf/},
  timestamp = {2015.11.24},
}
```

Be sure to re-run BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more, to fully propagate all changes.

---

*Addendum*: The [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) below produces the following output -- with no errors. Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytest.bib}
@electronic{ios9,
  author = {{Apple Inc.}},
  month  = {September},
  year   = {2015},
  title  = {{iOS Security}},
  url    = {https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf/},
  timestamp = {2015.11.24},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[conference,a4paper,twoside]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%    \usepackage{cite}
%    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%    \usepackage{color}
%    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    %\hyphenation{} %

\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  
\bibliography{mytest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I reran both programs 10 times + computer restart. Same error: 
l.9 ...= {https://ssl.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,,.,.,.,.,.,.,Security_Guide.pdf/},

The error output has a lot of space between iOS_ and security, i've illustrated this with the punctuation (look at hyperlink referrer)

Comment: Look at edit 2: for overview of situation

Comment: Added alternative

Comment: @Manumit - You haven't posted a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that actually generates the problem you say you're getting. In the absence of such an MWE, I've had to make some educated guesses at to the relevant structure of your code, but unfortunately I'm unable to replicate the problem (after I fixed up the bib entry). An "overview of the situation" is *not* a viable substitute for an MWE. Without an actual MWE to analyze, I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: Doesn't the image and preface in question cover all details?

Since you can't replicate the problem must be specific to me, but I have a feeling the root of the problem is the underscores in the apple link. EDIT: I tried changing to another random link, the error is now: l.15 @comment{jabref-meta: selector_
                                    publisher:} So there is something else generating the problem.

Comment: @Manumit - With the information you've provided so far, I am simply unable to replicate the problem you report you're getting. I don't have enough information to figure out what you're doing. (You're not running LaTeX on a bib file, are you?) Please put together an MWE that actually generates the error.

Comment: What do you mean running latex on bib file? I am using pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex on TexWorks along TexStudio

Comment: @Manumit - It was a wild guess. I've posted an addendum to my answer, with a full MWE. Please check if your TeX distribution generates an error with this MWE.

Comment: @Manumit: it sound like the underscore in `selector_publisher` is also causing troubles. Make sure *all* underscores are escaped.

Comment: @ErlendGraff - I'm sorry, but it's *horrible advice* to tell someone they should escape all underscores in a `url` field. For one, it's practically going to *guarantee* that the URL string will become unusable if it's purpose is to help readers find and download the document in question.

Comment: @Mico: well, actually I do mostly agree with you. I was mainly thinking of possible other fields in the bib file (if the jabref stuff was causing problems) - my bad! However, non-escaped underscores in the url field only works if you include the url package (which I personally think one should, but it is not necessarily given that it will always be used - although the OP *did* include it, which further strengthens your view). Still, I didn't quite get what you meant with the URL string becoming unusable? Only scenario I can think of, is if you try to grep for a url in the bibfile.

Comment: I put my data into your version, and it is now working :)
One small problem however is that the first page is sources only, and the rest of the page is empty. The article begins on page 2. The format required is that sources are at bottom of article, in the same page as ending of article.

Comment: solved: i put \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  
\bibliography{mytest} before \end{document}